# Sending and Receiving Network Requests in Kotlin with OkHttp

Tags: android, kotlin, okhttp

I'm using the code below to send and receive Network requests with OkHttp.
How can I know if the request is successfully sent before getting the response?
I want to add for example a trace to know that request is successfully sent and that I'm waiting now for the response.

```
val client = OkHttpClient()
val builder = FormBody.Builder()
val formBody = builder.build()
val request = Request.Builder()
      .url(url)
      .post(formBody)
      .build()
val response = client.newCall(request).execute()
val jsonDataString = response.body()?.string()
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the EventListener API https://square.github.io/okhttp/events/

```
#!/usr/bin/env kotlin

@file:Repository("https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/")
@file:DependsOn("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.0")
@file:CompilerOptions("-jvm-target", "1.8")

import okhttp3.Call
import okhttp3.EventListener
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient
import okhttp3.Request

val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
  .eventListener(object : EventListener() {
    override fun requestBodyEnd(call: Call, byteCount: Long) {
      println("requestBodyEnd: $call")
    }

    override fun responseHeadersStart(call: Call) {
      println("responseHeadersStart: $call")
    }
  })
  .build()

val request = Request.Builder()
  .url("https://httpbin.org/get")
  .build()

val body = client.newCall(request).execute().use {
  it.body!!.string()
}

println(body)
```

Example code (Kotlin script for Intellij) - name example.main.kts